# Uncaught error when using a self-referential hasMany relationship with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have defined the following model with Ember Data:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('person'),
  children: DS.hasMany('person')
});
```

Additionally, I've defined the following fixture data, which appropriately models the data, indicating that Ember Data has no problems modeling the data in this layout:

```
App.Person.FIXTURES = [
  {id: 1, name: "Dylan", parent: 2},
  {id: 2, name: "Stacey", children: [1,3]},
  {id: 3, name: "Londyn", parent: 2},
  {id: 4, name: "Kyle"}
];
```

When attempting to create a record, I get an incredibly unhelpful error message:

```
Uncaught #<error>
```

This only occurs when the children property is defined on the model. Removing it causes the record to be created successfully, without an error.

I've also made a simple example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/paquzoku/1/edit?html,js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
children: DS.hasMany('person', { async: true, inverse: 'parent' } )
```

You can read about inverse [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/#toc_explicit-inverses)

Comment: Have you gotten this working _without_ fixtures? Or even better, _without_ integer based IDs? I _had_ this working before I tried to improve my URLs, but it is now busted even with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474369/error-in-parent-child-relationships-in-ember